# youtube-dl '--add-metadata' not writing all metadata on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, video, youtube, metadata, youtube-dl

I have the latest version of youtube-dl installed as a environment variable for easy access in Command Prompt; I'd like to be able to simply type `youtube-dl`, then paste a link after it, all while downloading the best versions of the video and audio (then merging them), writing metadata and any subtitles to the final file after saving that file to a specific directory. I have a config file placed at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\youtube-dl\config.

```
#Continue on download errors
-i

# Video format
--hls-prefer-native
--format bestvideo+bestaudio/best
--merge-output-format mkv
--youtube-skip-dash-manifest

# Post-processing
--add-metadata
--embed-subs
--sub-lang en
--write-auto-sub
--convert-subtitles srt
--write-info-json

#Output
-o 'I:\Videos\YouTube\%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

The video description is written to the file in the comment field, but the video title, channel name, etc don't get written at all. I want to be able to sort by channel name in my file system; how can this be done?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that youtube-dlg, while slightly outdated, accomplishes this with this command:

```
youtube-dl.exe --newline -i --all-subs -o "F:\%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f mp4 --ignore-config --hls-prefer-native --add-metadata "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPV7JXTWPWI"
```

I tried adding `--hls-prefer-native` to no avail.